# TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView) is Upcasting or Downcasting?

Tags: java, android, downcast, upcasting

I am totally confused as to below code does upcast or downcast.
If so how?

Is `TextView` a super class, I presume its a sub-type of `View`.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: With buildgrade 3.0, you do not need cast this view. But TextView is a subview of View

Comment: Textview is a subview of view and view itself extends object. Take a look at this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, It's down casting.

This line :

```
findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Will return a view, But what kind of view it is ? (Button,List, TextView, ..)
Look at this example :

```
public abstract class Car{
    public abstract void power();
}

public class BMW extends Car{
    public void power(){
        System.out.println(2200);
    }
}

public class Benz extends Car{
    public void power(){
        System.out.println(2100);
    }
}
```

Creating an object of above classes (BMW,Benz)

```
BMW bmw = new BMW();
Benz benz = new Benz();

public class CarFactory{

    public void create(Car car){
        if(car instanceof Benz)
            Benz benz = (Benz) car;
        else 
            BMW bmw = (BMW) car ;
    }
}
```

Both of them (Benz, BMW) are explicit cast, like TextView.

I hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

its called DownCasting. you can understand deeply [here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~cannata/cs345/Class%20Notes/14%20Java%20Upcasting%20Downcasting.htm)

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

The code you have mentioned is **downcasting**. Because findViewByID returns a **View** Object and TextView is a child of a **View** class. When casting from parent to child is called **Down Casting** While castinrg from child to Parent is called **Upcasting**.

Note:  When you casting up, you normally do not need to cast cause of implicit casting.